# Custom exception class - weird behavior

Tags: c++, class, exception, try-catch

I've created a custom exception class `testException`.

`throw` creates a `testException` object which upon creation receives the desired name of the exception.

When a `testException` is caught (by reference) it should return the name of the exception by using the member function `Get.Exception`.

For some reason the function isn't called and instead I get the error:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of testException
> ```

I saw a similar example [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/155-exceptions-classes-and-inheritance/), which supposedly should work.

- Why do I get the above error?

---

**Code:**

`Exception.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef TESTEXCEPTION_H
#define TESTEXCEPTION_H

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class testException {
public:
    testException(string);
    string GetException();
    ~testException();
protected:
private:
    string myexception;
};

#endif // TESTEXCEPTION_H
```

`Exception.cpp`

```
#include "testException.h"

testException::testException(string temp) : myexception(temp) {
    // ctor
}

string testException::GetException() {
    return myexception;
}

testException::~testException() {
    // dtor
}
```

`main.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testException.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    throw testException ("Test");
    try {
        // Shouldn't be printed if exception is caught:
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    } catch (testException& first) {
        std::cerr << first.GetException();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing the exception outside of the `try` block.

```
int main() {
    throw testException("Test"); // Thrown in main function scope.
                                  // Will result in call to terminate.
    try {
        /* ... */
    } catch (testException& first) {
        // Only catches exceptions thrown in associated 'try' block.
        std::cerr << first.GetException();
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

An exception can only be caught when thrown *inside* of a try-catch clause. Throwing an exception in the `main` function scope will result in a call to `terminate`.

A `try` block will "try" to execute everything inside and if any exceptions are thrown along the way, they will be caught if the the associated exception handler takes a parameter with a type that the thrown exception is implicitly convertible to.

Once an exception is thrown the rest of the remaining statements inside of the try block will be skipped, all objects with automatic storage duration will be destroyed and the exception will be handled accordingly.

[**Live example with throw statement moved inside try-catch clause**](http://ideone.com/Jc53TJ)

Comment: When I tried to throw it inside the try block - same thing happened.
AFAIK - once an exception has been thrown (even if it is outside of a try block), a stack unwinding occurs until it is caught or a termination happens.

Comment: @Medvednic See the live example. Works as expected when the `throw` statement is moved inside the try-catch clause.

Comment: Thanks! silly me - I misunderstood the tutorial.
it said that exceptions don't have to be explicitly thrown inside the try block it self, what they actually meant is that a function inside a try block can throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

move throwing line: `throw testException ("Test");` into `try {} catch(catch (testException& first) {}` block.